# Tomcat Connection pool : few methods not releasing connection

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using tomcat connection pooling. But I was following exception 
`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object`

So I put in the following lines in context.xml to find the leak : 
`removeAbandoned="true" logAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="3"`

Then I started getting following exception `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace$AbandonedObjectException: DBCP object created 2015-01-17 22:12:18 by the following code was never closed:`
So I found two culprit methods that were causing this leak. The two methods have common way of getting connection i.e. calling unwrap to get access to driver specific connection.

```
try (Connection conn = DataSourceConnectionPool.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        OracleCallableStatement cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(MIGRATE_ACCOUNT)) {
        ...
        ....
)
```

Important think to notice is that I am using try block from JDK7 i.e. Automatic Resource Management, so i dont need the finally block. Connection closing is handled by JDK automatically. But why this unwrapped connection is not closing. And when I am trying to do following :

```
try (Connection poolConn = DataSourceConnectionPool.getConnection();
    Connection conn = poolConn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

I am getting `java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.` So how close this connection. Do I have to do it manually without using try block? Shouldn't try block handle be able to handle this?

Comment: First question I have is how were you able to verify that the .unwrap() code is where the leak is occurring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is incorrect usage of a connection pool. You should never call `close()` on an unwrapped connection.

The normal flow of using a pooled connection is

1. Get the `Connection`, the pool gets a physical connection and returns it wrapped in its own wrapper
2. You use the `Connection`
3. You call `close()` on the `Connection`. This doesn't actually *close* anything, the pool's wrapper intercepts the `close()` call and simply returns the (still active) connection to the pool.

This works because the pool has a wrapper class, say `PoolableConnection` that `implements Connection`. `PoolableConnection` delegates to the underlying connection for carrying out actual work, but it implements (amongst other things) `close()` differently. This destroys the current `PoolableConnection` wrapper and returns the underying `Connection` to the connection pool. For example.

This way, your program logic can get a connection from a `DataSource`, use the `Connection` and then `close()`, just as it would a normal, unpooled, `Connection`.

It's exactly this transparency that makes connection pools so easy to use.

Now, when you call `unwrap`, the `PooledConnection` gives you access to it's internal, real, `Connection` delegate.

What *you* do is call `close()` *on the delegate*!

This has two effects:

1. it does not call `close()` on `PooledConnection`, so the the `Connection` does not get returned to the pool.
2. it closes the underying connection from underneath the pool. This shouldn't be a problem, as the pool would deal with dropped connections itself.

So you need to be very careful. **Always** call `close()` on the `Connection` you have gotten from the pool, to return it to the pool. **Never** call `close()` on the underlying connection.

So your code should be:

```
try (final Connection poolConn = DataSourceConnectionPool.getConnection()) {
    final Connection conn = poolConn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    //do stuff with conn
    //do not close conn!!
}
//poolConn is returned to the pool
```