# Reuse open connection from BasicDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am creating a new **BasicDataSource** object and set in it username, password, etc.
Once i call the **dataSource.getConnection(),** a new connection is created.

My requirement is to able to reuse the already opened connection. 
In the Java Doc of **getConnection()** it is written:

*Create (if necessary) and return a connection to the database*

Which apparently i can't understand *WHEN* is this necessary.

There is a **setMaxActive** that limits the maximum connections, but this looks to be kind of limiting currently for me as once the getConnection() is called, it tries to create a new connection with the database instead of getting the existing one.

Question: Is there away to set somehow the DataSource in that way in order to create just one connection and to retrieve the same connection always when getConnection() is called ? Any other workaround ?

Comment: Look at the [configuration page for DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html). You will find a number of parameters there, `initialSize` is the one you should be looking at. Connections pools are complicated, pick settings that make sense for you and let it do its job.

Comment: This would mean that i need an initialSize=1 . What will happen once my application does access the getConnection() again ?

Comment: If the connection is not is use, and it hasn't expired or been destroyed for some other reason (see the parameters I linked), then the same connection would be returned. If the connection is in use, and `max...` is set to `>1` then a new connection will be opened and returned. If the connection is in use and `max...` is set to `1` then you will have resource exhaustion, the outcome of which is again specified in the configuration parameters I linked.

Comment: If your pool is always opening new connections, make sure that you are _closing_ the connections you get from the pool (this will not actually close them but return them to the pool - see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28002442/2071828)) as otherwise you will not be returning connections to the pool - and the pool will think they are still in use. See the properties related to abandoned connections on the configuration page I linked.